# Issue in reading the contents of log file every 30 minutes

Tags: linux, grep

I need to read the contents of a file `mycustomfile.log` every 30 minutes in linux

I tried `egrep "06:00| 06:30"`

But am not getting the results I want.

```
06:00:24  rdy->395  bsy->205  ka->29 
06:30:27  rdy->339  bsy->261  ka->40 
07:00:30  rdy->259  bsy->341  ka->80 
**07:06:30  rdy->282  bsy->318  ka->73** 
**07:07:30  rdy->234  bsy->366  ka->80** 
07:30:32  rdy->455  bsy->445  ka->85
```

the above results  highlighted with `**` are in amongst correct entries.  I need to exclude them, and I need to see the results in 30 minutes interval.

What am I missing?

UPDATE 
 Below is my input file :

```
[Thu Mar 30 00:00:37 2017] [notice] mpmstats: rdy 26 bsy 49 rd 45 wr 1 ka 3 log 0 dns 0 cls 0

[Thu Mar 30 00:10:38 2017] [notice] mpmstats: rdy 46 bsy 54 rd 53 wr 0 ka 1 log 0 dns 0 cls 0

[Thu Mar 30 00:20:39 2017] [notice] mpmstats: rdy 55 bsy 45 rd 45 wr 0 ka 0 log 0 dns 0 cls 0

[Thu Mar 30 00:30:39 2017] [notice] mpmstats: rdy 48 bsy 52 rd 51 wr 0 ka 1 log 0 dns 0 cls 0

[Thu Mar 30 00:40:40 2017] [notice] mpmstats: rdy 74 bsy 26 rd 23 wr 0 ka 1 log 0 dns 0 cls 2

[Thu Mar 30 00:50:41 2017] [notice] mpmstats: rdy 44 bsy 14 rd 12 wr 0 ka 2 log 0 dns 0 cls 0

[Thu Mar 30 01:00:41 2017] [notice] mpmstats: rdy 41 bsy 9 rd 9 wr 0 ka 0 log 0 dns 0 cls 0

[Thu Mar 30 01:10:42 2017] [notice] mpmstats: rdy 39 bsy 11 rd 5 wr 0 ka 6 log 0 dns 0 cls 0
[Thu Mar 30 01:20:42 2017] [notice] mpmstats: rdy 45 bsy 5 rd 5 wr 0 ka 0 log 0 dns 0 cls 0
[Thu Mar 30 01:30:43 2017] [notice] mpmstats: rdy 31 bsy 19 rd 18 wr 0 ka 1 log 0 dns 0 cls 0
[Thu Mar 30 01:40:44 2017] [notice] mpmstats: rdy 59 bsy 16 rd 16 wr 0 ka 0 log 0 dns 0 cls 0
[Thu Mar 30 01:50:44 2017] [notice] mpmstats: rdy 62 bsy 13 rd 13 wr 0 ka 0 log 0 dns 0 cls 0
[Thu Mar 30 02:00:45 2017] [notice] mpmstats: rdy 70 bsy 5 rd 5 wr 0 ka 0 log 0 dns 0 cls 0
[Thu Mar 30 02:10:45 2017] [notice] mpmstats: rdy 69 bsy 6 rd 5 wr 0 ka 1 log 0 dns 0 cls 0
[Thu Mar 30 02:20:46 2017] [notice] mpmstats: rdy 57 bsy 18 rd 18 wr 0 ka 0 log 0 dns 0 cls 0
[Thu Mar 30 02:30:47 2017] [notice] mpmstats: rdy 69 bsy 6 rd 6 wr 0 ka 0 log 0 dns 0 cls 0
[Thu Mar 30 02:40:47 2017] [notice] mpmstats: rdy 69 bsy 6 rd 6 wr 0 ka 0 log 0 dns 0 cls 0
[Thu Mar 30 02:50:48 2017] [notice] mpmstats: rdy 73 bsy 2 rd 2 wr 0 ka 0 log 0 dns 0 cls 0
[Thu Mar 30 03:30:50 2017] [notice] mpmstats: rdy 72 bsy 3 rd 3 wr 0 ka 0 log 0 dns 0 cls 0
[Thu Mar 30 03:40:51 2017] [notice] mpmstats: rdy 72 bsy 3 rd 3 wr 0 ka 0 log 0 dns 0 cls 0
[Thu Mar 30 03:50:52 2017] [notice] mpmstats: rdy 74 bsy 1 rd 1 wr 0 ka 0 log 0 dns 0 cls 0
[Thu Mar 30 04:00:52 2017] [notice] mpmstats: rdy 74 bsy 1 rd 1 wr 0 ka 0 log 0 dns 0 cls 0
[Thu Mar 30 04:10:53 2017] [notice] mpmstats: rdy 73 bsy 2 rd 2 wr 0 ka 0 log 0 dns 0 cls 0
[Thu Mar 30 04:20:54 2017] [notice] mpmstats: rdy 64 bsy 11 rd 11 wr 0 ka 0 log 0 dns 0 cls 0
[Thu Mar 30 04:30:54 2017] [notice] mpmstats: rdy 71 bsy 4 rd 4 wr 0 ka 0 log 0 dns 0 cls 0
```

Comment: Can you please provide sample of the input file, and a sample of expected result?

Comment: yes, i have provided the output its generated . i need to avoid the 07:06:30 entry and 07:07 entry . it has to be in the interval of 30 minutes, but here it sometimes show as 1 minute interval.

Comment: the command you entered cannot possibly have produced that output from that input file. Please could you show us exactly what you want to see?

Comment: In a recent system you can use journalctl.  `journalctll -u mpmstats --since 06:00 --until 06:30`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grep pattern you are using can provides minutes:seconds instead of hours:minutes

The following grep will be more accurate:

Note that I added ":" after the minutes, to indicates that there are also seconds afterwards.

```
egrep "06:00:|06:30:"
```

Or a more general grep:

```
egrep ":00:|:30:"
```

Comment: Thanks Yaron , for your help.  egrep ":00:|:30:"  is working peRFectly.